# UWP app deployment via download

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I want to deploy my in-house UWP app only to selected Windows Phone 10 devices via a download link.
This already works for iOS and Android, but I have troubles with WinPhone 10.

On my development device, I can just download and install the created appxbundle file. However, it seems that the appxbundle does not include the dependencies (Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx, Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.Debug.14.00.appx). Therefore the installation does not work on devices, which have never been used to develop the app (and therefore do not have the dependencies installed).

Is there a way to create a complete appxbundle which also installs the dependencies?

Comment: Have read this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829321/install-an-appx-or-appxbundle-in-a-windows-phone-10) ?

Comment: try updating Windows 10 mobile SDK Image and mobile itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building the app in release mode solved the problem.

The .NET native toolchain includes all the required dependencies into the executable and therefore the installation of the dependencies is not required.